# Overriding existing lock by dead process '12224' (I am process '2516')

Tags: overriding, theano-cuda

Using Theano backend.
(57720L, 51L) (57720L, 5L) (850L, 51L) (850L,)
WARNING (theano.gof.compilelock): Overriding existing lock by dead process '12224' (I am process '2516')
what is the meaning of that, and how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this warning message is due to force-stopping a previous execution which held a lock to the Theano cache; the new process detects this and acquires the lock for itself.

You may simply ignore the message since it would not affect the performance. However, you may try deleting the theano cache folder as mentioned [here](https://discourse.pymc.io/t/pymc3-2-theano-crashes/519).